# How can I start activity with a navigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

I use an activity without NavigationDrawer and I need to pass into an activity with NavigationDrawer.

I tried with this code:

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,NavigationDrawer.class);
startActivity(in);
```

but **logcat** show me this error:

[image]

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: The next time don't post images with errors, post your real code using `code tag`.

Comment: post your xml and as well as full log in text, as per the the partial shown log. your xml is not right.